# How to derive the asymptotic distribution under the alternative hypothesis?

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics

In the class, my professor introduced the ADF test, and I suddenly realized that it seems that all tests are under the null hypothesis. I'm curious that if it is possible to make the judgement under the alternative hypothesis or find out the distribution under the alternative hypothesis.

I have found a question in Stackexchange which suggests that for the situation of $\alpha = 1$ and $\alpha \neq 0$, we can look the problem as $\alpha = \hat{\alpha} + \hat{\gamma}$ so that we can derive the distribution under the alternative hypothesis, but I don't know how to deal with the problem such as $H_0$: $\alpha = 1$ and $H_{A}$:$\alpha < 1$ like what ADF test states.

Is there any textbook or other materials which discuss this kind of problem?

Comment: This is a question for your professor or a classmate, not for this forum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reason given in a previous comment